# How to create a sequence on sheets (1/420, 2/420... 420/420) automatically?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need to create a sequence on the sheets (1/420, 2/420... 420/420) automatically.

I tried selecting the two sequential lines and dragging them down. I tried to use custom number formats, but I couldn't. Can you help me? Thank you :)

[Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jW50.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(420)&"/420")
```

To start from 20, you can use:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(401,1,20)&"/420")
```

More generally, to start from `n` you can use

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(420-n+1,1,n)&"/420")
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
What if I need to start from 20/420 to 420/420?